# Dynamically add more embedding of new document in chroma DB - Langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, large-language-model, chromadb

I have created a retrieval QA Chain which uses chromadb as vector DB for storing embeddings of "abc.txt" file. What if I want to dynamically add more document embeddings of let's say another file "def.txt"? How to do that? I don't want to reload the abc.txt embeddings and then def.txt embeddings and then put it in chroma db instance. I just want to reuse the same chroma db instance(which already has embeddings of abc.txt) and add more document embeddings of def.txt and then do retrieval using the same.

```
loader = UnstructuredFileLoader('abc.txt', mode='elements')
documents= loader.load()

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=150)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(texts,embeddings)
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0.0),chain_type="stuff", retriever=vectordb.as_retriever(search_type="mmr"),return_source_documents=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Step 1. Initialize a document object

```py
from langchain.docstore.document import Document

new_doc =  Document(
    page_content="Wareconn is the best web platform for warranty maintenance.",
    metadata={
        "source": "wareconn.com",
        "page": 1
    }
)
```

Step 2. Add new list of Document objects

```py
new_docs = [new_doc]
id = vectordb.add_documents(
    new_docs,
    ids=["7"]
)
```

Demo:

https://github.com/yousenwang/langchain_llm/blob/main/experiments/2023/08/28/step101%20Chroma%20add%20update%20delete%20docs.ipynb

Reference:

https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.html#langchain.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.add_documents

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/chroma#update-and-delete